# SQL convert perfomance optimization

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

This is the query which is formed in the backend and sent to the database:

```
SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[ID], [c].[LastName]
FROM [ClientDonor] AS [c]
WHERE NOT ([c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(1 AS bit)) 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), [c].[ID]) IN 
(N'ef47913f-8960-46ad-f8ff-08d865b62242', N'1617bed9-4369-44eb-b605-08d895a537c9', N'ebd998be-9262-40aa-b604-08d895a537c9', N'6f472069-bd82-4686-7381-08d89800b4ae', N'a688c8bd-c045-42bd-737f-08d89800b4ae', N'292bc19d-1d1b-49ce-7384-08d89800b4ae')
```

The problem is that in order to compare every id from db with the list of ids I need to convert it from `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` to `VARCHAR`. This operation takes a lot of time in spite of database size, and I can't find any way to optimize it. I want to get rid of this `CONVERT`, but it's impossible to pass a list of ids from backend as list of `UNQUEIDENTIFIER`s.
The query is created by Entity Framework Core.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you converting them to a `varchar` at all? Also, you're not only converting your (I assume) `uniqueidentifier` to a `varchar`, you're then converting it to an `nvarchar` too. Why are your `uniqueidentifier` literals `nvarchar`s, and why convert the column..?

Comment: This query is created by entity framework core automatically.

Comment: There is *no* mention that this query is generated by EF in your question, @Vlad ...

Comment: `NOT ([c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(1 AS bit)) ` seems odd too; why not just `c.IsDeleted = 0`?

Comment: Your question is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). It seems like the *real* question you are asking here isn't how to do a performant `CONVERT` in the `WHERE` (which is an XY Problem unto itself, because the problem is the `CONVERT` itself), but how to pass a `uniqueidentifier` as a parameter in EF, @Vlad. That is the question you should be asking. You'll need to ask a new question though, as that is *completely* different to the question asked here and you've already received an answer to the question asked.

Comment: "NOT..." string is generated by entity type builder
builder.HasQueryFilter(entity => !entity.IsDeleted);

Comment: The EF query should be posted instead. The problem is that you are trying to compare strings instead of comparing `Guid`s. Please also add the table and index definitions, and share a link to the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Answer (score 1):

> it's impossible to pass a list of ids from backend as list of `UNQUEIDENTIFIER`s

No it's not. Just pass literal strings, that are valid `uniqueidentifier` values to the RDBMS, and it'll work fine. The literal strings will be converted to a `uniqueidentifer` (not the column to a `varchar`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeUID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
VALUES(NEWID()),(NEWID());
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeUID IN ('ef47913f-8960-46ad-f8ff-08d865b62242', '1617bed9-4369-44eb-b605-08d895a537c9');
```

This will result in a SARGable query. As can be seen in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc3c6e58ba434590a189fa4b36c20502), where an index seek is performed.